# Favorite questions and answers from the fourth quarter of 2014

Tags: discussion, blog

Please link to your favorite questions and answers which were either asked or answered from October 1st 2014 through December 31 2014.

Your answers will be compiled into a end of the year blog post like previous [quarterly posts](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/category/qotw/).

I will be using DavRob60's queries for a baseline, but I really appreciate people voicing the ones they really enjoyed. Maybe you feel like you answered one really well, even if it didn't receive a lot of votes. Let me know about it.

**What was the best answer (IYHO) provided to a question that was closed?**

- [Questions with most **Votes** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106579/questions-with-most-votes-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2013/07/01)
- [Questions with most **View** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106705/questions-with-most-view-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2013/07/01)
- [Questions with **best answer** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106709/questions-with-best-answer-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2013/07/01)

Answer (score 3):

An awful, awful, awful, awful question that prompted an excellent answer: [Is a lightsaber's hilt resizeable?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/76846/is-a-lightsabers-hilt-resizeable)

This one got me a Red Baron hat: [Why did Lucas choose the word "Force"?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/76163/why-did-lucas-choose-the-word-force) ([one of only 26 awarded](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/01/so-long-winter-bash-2014/?cb=1) - whoo!)

Comment: And a possible contender for the "reversal" badge if I can get a few more votes :-)

Answer (score 2):

I quite liked this question; ["Why is Wednesday Addams named Wednesday?"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/72031/why-is-wednesday-addams-named-wednesday).

I thought I'd found the definitive answer, only to discover that there was an even stronger one waiting in the wings...

---

[This](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/75574) was a great answer from Thaddeus to ["What's under the crystal bridge in Asgard?"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/75572/whats-under-the-crystal-bridge-in-asgard).

I especially enjoyed the maps and pictures

---

And as much as I hate to blow my own trumpet, [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/71566/20774) to the question of [why there aren't any animals in "the Matrix"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/71564/in-the-matrix-why-are-there-no-animals) required a considerable amount of research time and effort cataloging and collating pictures.

---

Comment: You love to blow your own trumpet.

Comment: @JackBNimble - Damn, you've found out my most closely guarded secret.

Comment: Speaking of [blowing-trumpets](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1vATHPpqS7Q).

Answer (score 1):

I thought the best question was [Why didn't Qui-Gon Jinn use his Jedi mind tricks to exchange his Republic credits?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/72431/why-didnt-qui-gon-jinn-use-his-jedi-mind-tricks-to-exchange-his-republic-credit) It exposed what nearly amounts to a plot hole, as demonstrated by the poor answer (as noted in the comments, I think the answer was poor because of the filmmakers, not @Richard).

Answer (score 1):

I really liked [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/76511/unknown-feature-on-middle-earths-map/76512): **Unknown feature on Middle Earth's map?**

That asked about the island in the sea of Rhun.

<sub>I also liked my answer there:</sub>

[Because I found some interesting discussions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/76512/19374)